# How to integrate MS Office 365 word text editor on the web page

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-5, office365, laravel-5.3

I would be so glad if anyone could answer my question. I'm developing a correspondent management system in laravel 5.3, i have found some jQuery rich editors(plugins).

But the main issue is that i want to integrate the MS Office 365 word text editor on my web page to allow the user to write a letter just like in the MS word text editor, is there a possibility to do that, please give me some recommendation. Have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will be able to integrate the MS Office 365 word editor on a webpage. I may be mistaken ... maybe there is a way to do it by wrapping it in for instance C# and using that component on your page. Since this is tagged with Laravel it might do more bad than good to mix in even more technologies/platforms.

However ... what you can do is use one of the many light weight editors running as a plugin on the frontend.

This might be of some inspiration for you: https://www.sitepoint.com/10-best-html-wysiwyg-plugins/